# Regarding XSD validation

Tags: alfresco

I have created xsd then webform within a project inside alfresco.if an mandatary field is empty then it show message that field must not be empty indicating that field. Please let me know that where is java code writen to validate those fields.can i modify those code or not.

Answer (score 0):

**Java XML Validation** API can be used to validate XML against an XSD. javax.xml.validation.Validator class is used in this program to validate xml file against xsd file.

```
public static boolean validateXMLSchema(String xsdPath, String xmlPath)
{

    try {
            SchemaFactory factory =
                    SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
            Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new File(xsdPath));
            Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
            validator.validate(new StreamSource(new File(xmlPath)));
        } catch (IOException | SAXException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception: "+e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
        return true;
}
```